# Why consecutive show and hide behaves buggy in this code?

Tags: jquery

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnycpp/fMXyP/5/

Consecutive show,hide calls produces a bug, Animation stops and does not resume sometimes. Is this jQuery bug or bug in my code?

Here is the code copy-pasted from jsfiddle.

```
myButtonManual.on("click", function() {
  isVisible = !isVisible;      
  myHero.stop(true,false);      
  if(isVisible) {        
    myHero.show('slow');
    myButtonManual.text("Manual Hide");
  } else {        
    myHero.hide('slow');
    myButtonManual.text("Manual Show");
  }
```

[image]

Comment: In actual usecase, Show and hide are two different API calls, not possible to convert them to toggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't a bug.

Taking a look at this line:

```
myHero.stop(true,false);
```

When you stop a `.hide()` at the middle of it without jumping to the end of animation, an element that is visible will stay [`visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Your logic `isVisible = !isVisible` will be broken then as `.stop()`ing a `hide()` leaves the element still visible, meaning that the next call to the handler will execute `.show()` on a `visible` element that will have absolutely no effect.

Workarounds include:

- Remove the `.stop()`, this will queue the `show()` and execute it after the `hide()` concludes;
- Use `.stop(true)` - equivalent to `.stop(true, true)` -, this will be rather bluntly as it will force the animation to conclude as it suddenly starts the next;

**Edit:** The closest way to reproduce a `.toggle()`-like behavior using the `.show()` and `.hide()` methods is to simply add a `.css('display', 'none')` before calling `.show()`, this will ensure that `.show()` has the desired effect:

```
isVisible = !isVisible;
myHero.stop(true, false);
if (isVisible) {
  myHero.css('display', 'none').show('slow');
} else {
  myHero.hide('slow');
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fMXyP/17/)

If the element is already hidden, the `.css` will have no effect; if the element is partially shown, it will hide it ensuring that `.show()` executes instead of being ignored due to the element being considered `visible`.

This has the same effect as the `.stop(true, false).toggle()`, but works using the 2 different `.show()`/`.hide()` methods as requested.

Comment: Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for an appropriate one. Removing the `.stop()` line will behave as the automatic toggle; using `stop(true)` will work as well but is rather bluntly.

Comment: I'm not satisfied with this explanation really. The functionality is OK if you just wait for the animation to complete. Therefore I believe there is something to do with the timely dispatching of the click events.

Comment: @CyberDude Mind you re-read my answer? `.stop(true, false)` stops the animation at the mid of it without completing the animation, which leaves a `.hide()` incomplete meaning the element is still visible. Then when you call `.show()` on it due to OP assuming that each click toggles the visibility: `isVisible = !isVisible`, the `.show()` function has absolutely no effect as the element is already `visible`. Sorry, but I can't put it in any simpler terms.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, Your answer is perfect. I will check for the solution and post it as comment in short time.

Comment: I'm looking a for a better work-around, `.animate()` is usually easier to workaround than with these booleans and predefined show/hide functions which animate the element dimensions.. But I'll try to find a better and simple workaround meanwhile as well.

Comment: It looks like same is true for fadeIn and fadeOut also, jQuery animations are not pause and resumable.

Comment: To stop the animation in the middle it means that when reaching the `stop` line the animation must already be ongoing. Does that mean that the click handler executions overlap (temporally)?

Comment: console.log is coming properly. Checked.

Comment: @SunnyShah check if this is acceptable for your use case: http://jsfiddle.net/fMXyP/11/ - oh wait, that's basically the same as the show/hide, sec while I adapt to use the 2 different APIs

Comment: @CyberDude Yes and no, OP's issue is when you click consecutively (while one animation is executing) which then calls `.stop(true, false)` leaving the `hide()` incomplete - the element will still be visible but OP's `isVisible` flag will be wrong, which calls `.show()` on it while the element is `visible`. An element is considered `visible` as long as it occupies space in the page layout.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I understand the logic of your answer. What I wanted to clarify is the async nature of the event dispatching (the handler of a second click will not wait for the completion of the handler for the first click thus stopping an animation already in progress)

Comment: @CyberDude it isn't the handler itself, the handler will be called as soon as the button is clicked. The `.stop(true, false)` inside the handler will stop the element from being hidden, thus the element that would be hidden if the animation had completed is now still visible.

Comment: @SunnyShah is the `.toggle()` method usable in your use case or do it has to be `.show()` and `.hide()`? Seems like you want the latter, but in that case, you would like to stop the animation partially and resume the next exactly as `.toggle` does? I fail to see how it is differently from using `toggle` itself. Also, if you use `fadeIn/fadeOut`, that is easier to manipulate as you could use `fadeTo('slow', 1)`/`fadeTo('slow', 0, function() { $(this).hide(); })` to better manipulate these partially hidden elements

Comment: Here's the fiddle using `fadeTo`: http://jsfiddle.net/fMXyP/13/ - it is basically the same as `fadeToggle` though which has the same behavior as `toggle`.

Comment: @SunnyShah updated answer with a definite fix, just give a holler in case you need something different. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, Excellent!